# Convert the post date to Jalali date in WordPress

Tags: php, farsi, jalali-calendar

I need to convert the date of my posts to the Jalali calendar.

This is the code I’m using to display the date of the posts in WordPress. I tried using some plugins to change the date but they did not work.

```php
echo get_the_title()
    ? '<span>'.date( ' j ',strtotime($post->post_date)).'</span>'.date( '/F , Y',strtotime($post->post_date))
    : '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"><span>'.date( ' j ',strtotime($post->post_date)).'</span>'.date( '/F , Y',strtotime($post->post_date)).'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `IntlDateFormatter` class inside a function.

```
function convertDateTime($datetimestr, $timezone='Asia/Tehran') {
    $timestamp = strtotime($datetimestr);

    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        'fa-IR',
        IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        $timezone,
        IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    );

    return $formatter->format($timestamp);
}
```

And then `echo convertDateTime($post->post_date)` when showing your posts.

For `2023-10-14 12:00:00` this gives me `۱۴۰۲/۷/۲۲, ۱۵:۳۰` which according to Google translates to `22.07.1402, 15:30`.

[The IntlDateFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)